# connect to smartcard reader via java script

Tags: javascript, web, smartcard

is there any way to connect to a smart card reader using java script?

my reader standard is PC/SC and I want to read data from card connected to it via javascript running on web page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smartcard reader access from a web browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750928/smartcard-reader-access-from-a-web-browser)

Comment: Please refer to my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript cannot directly communicate with your reader though it can communicate with a java applet. See if your hardware provides such an applet.

Or see the question below for more options:

[Smartcard reader access from a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750928/smartcard-reader-access-from-a-web-browser)

Comment: java applet not supported in any browser except IE and Firefox is this normal?

Comment: I have heard about their planning of dropping the support for NPAPI in version 45.

Comment: they do it and chrome 45 now not support NPAPI, firefox i don't know if they decide to drop this or not