# Reading Smart Card with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, smartcard, smartcard-reader

I am developing a web application but as per requirements of the clients I need to read smart card on client side i.e web page.

How can we read a Smart Card using JavaScript?

Comment: Could it help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6750928/smartcard-reader-access-from-a-web-browser

Comment: @VasilyVlasov No, As it is using Java Applet. I want to perform tasks in Javascript

Comment: The dup is good, read between the lines: not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Architectures to access Smart Card from a generic browser? Or: How to bridge the gap from browser to PC/SC stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807038/architectures-to-access-smart-card-from-a-generic-browser-or-how-to-bridge-the)